# Finding the CDF of a min function where one of the arguments is a constant

Tags: random-variable

I'm reading through my lecture notes that the CDF of the random variable $Z = \min(D, a)$ where $a$ is a constant can be written as:

$P[\min(D,a) \le y] = \begin{cases} 1 &,a\le y \\ P(D \le y)&, a>y\end{cases}$

I can understand why it's $1$ for $a<y$. However, I think the second argument is valid only for $D<a$, but in case of $D>a$ the probability must be zero. So the previous function should be written as something like this:

$P[ \min(D,a) \le y] = \begin{cases} 1 &, a<y \\ P(D \le y)&, a>y,D<a \\0&, a>y, D>a\end{cases} $

am I right? or does the first function implies the second function somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deal with the case where $a>y$ you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(\min (D, a) \leqslant y) = \mathbb{P}(D \leqslant y \text{ or }a \leqslant y) = \mathbb{P}(D \leqslant y) = \text{Some value}.$$

In your attempted solution you have pulled the random variable $D$ out of its probability statement and treated it as if it were an argument value, which is invalid.  It is important to understand that a probability statement concerning a random variable $D$ is telling you the probability of some event concerning that random variable.  This probability **is not a function of** $D$ -- the probability operator "integrates out" the random variable.

---

You can of course say that the *event* $\{ \min(D, a) \leqslant y \}$ occurs if $a \leqslant y$ or $D \leqslant y$, but the *probability* of this event is not a function of $D$.

Comment: For $$\mathbb{P}(\min (D, a) \leqslant y) = \mathbb{P}(D \leqslant y \text{ or }a \leqslant y)$$, is it valid regardless of what $a$ and $y$ relate to each other? Can you explain more please?

Comment: Yes, it is valid.  In fact, you can remove the probability operator from the outside and simply recognise that in order to have $\min (D, a) \leqslant y$ you must have $D \leqslant y$ or $a \leqslant y$ (or both).  In other words, for the minimum of two values to be below some threshold, either the first value has to be below that threshold, or the second value has to be below that threshold, or both.   This holds regardless of whether the values are random or fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $X$ is a continuous random variable, one can find the CDF of $Z=\min(X,a)$ as:

$\Pr(Z\le z)=\Pr(\min(X,a)\le z)$

$\qquad\qquad\quad=\Pr(\min(X,a)\le z,X\le a)+\Pr(\min(X,a)\le z,X>a)$

$\qquad\qquad\quad=\begin{cases}\Pr(X\le z,X\le a)+\Pr(X>a)&,\text{ if }z\ge a\\\Pr(X\le z,X\le a)&,\text{ if }z<a\end{cases}$

$\qquad\qquad\quad=\begin{cases}\Pr(X\le a)+\Pr(X>a)=1&,\text{ if }z\ge a\\\Pr(X\le z)&,\text{ if }z<a\end{cases}$

So I think the first argument suffices as far as the exact form of the CDF is concerned.

Comment: I don't think there are values of $x$ satisfy the inequality $min(x,a) \ge a $ I'm saying this because in the third step you assumed that if $z \ge a$ then it means $min(X,a) \le z$  equivalent to $X \le z$. How is that be possible?

Comment: No. $\{\min(X,a)\le z\}\cap \{X\le a\}$ implies $\{X\le z\}\cap \{X\le a\}$ irrespective of whether $z\ge a$ or not.